# HTML Javascript onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, html

The onclick function is not being called and I am straight directed to Google.com. Should have a javascript pop-up when user clicks on the button

```
<a onclick="myfunction();" class="button_1" href="http://google.com"><p>Submit</p></a>
```

Comment: You haven't defined `myfunction` (at least not in the code you provided, you need a [mcve])

Comment: After `myfunction();` add `return false;`, and it won't go to the link.

Comment: `href="http://google.com"` using href with value will trigger redirecton to website mentioned. So, just remove that and your function will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create the method myFuntion() it should work, without problems.

```js
function myfunction(){
     alert("onclick called");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myfunction();" class="button_1" href="http://google.com"><p>Submit</p></a>
```